# Retrieve Cover Art for a Soundtrack on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

is there a way of obtaining cover art for a soundtrack? My app can provide the artist and sound track, but the different cover websites I have been looking through offer no convenient way of obtaining it. Is there a class available maybe?

Thank you

Edit: I am streaming music, the tracks are not in the devce's music library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the title of the soundtrack album, I suggest that you try using the Discogs.com API (http://www.discogs.com/help/api). Even though it is mostly a user-driven database and the quality of some cover art is not great, should be a good place to start. The API works by giving you results for simple queries using *any* information you may have about the album, and then you can pick which results are better suited.

Comment: I can't get this to work. For example here, `http://www.discogs.com/release/1?f=xml&api_key=<API_Key>` it takes an integer for the release? Why is that??

Comment: That's the release ID. You find it by doing a query for the album name/artist name, e.g. http://www.discogs.com/search?type=releases&q=title:%22The Sound Of Music%22%20AND%20artist:%22Various%22&f=xml gives you a URI to the release, where the release ID can then be parsed out and inserted into your query above.

Comment: this just doesn't work out. I keep getting garbage back with no image links, i'll have to look for a different way. I get things like this `Diana RossMy Old Piano12"Funk / SoulDiscoUK1980AMy Old PianoBernard Edwards & Nile RodgersProducer3:52BWhere Did We Go WrongRonald MillerProducerTom BairdProducer4:24` which contains no cover information. I'll need to look for a different way.

Comment: That's why you have to do two queries. I just ran "My Old Piano" by Diana Ross. First match was release 113980. Then I ran that with with release query - http://www.discogs.com/release/113980?f=xml - this gives me the art in the <images/> element: <image height="594" type="primary" uri="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-113980-1280144535.jpeg" uri150="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-150-113980-1280144535.jpeg" width="600"/>

Comment: could we exchange code via e-mail if possible? My implementation doesn't work right, but yours seems to? my e-mail is david.schiefer[at]writeitstudios.com

Answer (score 1):

I found a combination of MusicBrainz and Amazon give good results - MusicBrainz for the searching and identification by album/artist name, and Amazon for the cover art (MusicBrainz provides the ASIN to link between the two). More work, but more accuracy in my experience.

Comment: how do i get cover art programmatically, Dan?

Comment: You use the MusicBrainz and Amazon APIs... http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XMLWebService and https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Answer (score 0):

If the track isn't in the media library, then you can't use the media player API to get the information you need. You'll need to use a third-party service. Gracenote (owner of the CDDB) provide such a service, however I have no idea what they charge and whether it's any good.

Comment: Gracenote charges money to use their service, it's pretty complicated.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at [MPMediaItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaItem/valueForProperty%3a) and [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765)

hope it helps

Comment: I am streaming music, so it doesn't sorry. Thanks for your answer though! I'll need to get it of the Internet somehow.